# Snail - a wall Climber problem using sys.stdin

Tags: python

> **Snail - a wall Climber**
>
> Takes in non-negative integers `n`, `m` and `H` where:
> `n` - Climbs up by this many steps
> `m` - Slides down by this many steps
> `H` - Height that needs reaching
>
> and days it takes to reach the height.
>
> **Example 1:**
> `3 2 11`
>
> should output:
> `9`
>
> **Example 2**:
> `5 2 9`
>
> output:
> `3`

I've come across this problem which I haven't attempted any that require me to use sys.stdin. I'm not sure how to go about this in VS Code either.

Any help would be appreciated on this problem.

```
import sys

for line in sys.stdin:
     print(line, end="")
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to be reading in from `sys.stdin` and not just reading args from `sys.argv`?

Comment: You didn't specify why you are required to use `sys.stdin`. You haven't indicated that you've looked up any examples on how it's used, or any information on it whatsoever. You've shown us a homework problem prompt and then said you have no idea where to start, and are just expecting us to do all of your work for you? How could you learn anything that way? And that's academic dishonesty. You need to read: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822)

Answer (score 0):

Most online coding problems provide the input over lines from standard input.

You simply need to parse the input, for example

```
import sys

def solve(n, m, H):
    return None  # TODO: Implement

for line in sys.stdin:
    if line:
        parts = line.split()
        if len(parts) != 3:
            raise Error('Invalid Input. Needs 3 columns')
        n = int(parts[0])
        m = int(parts[1])
        H = int(parts[2])
        
        print(solve(n, m, H))
```

It's unclear what the output number represents, so it is hard to help further